# How do I get Rake TestTask to execute a Ruby script before testing?

Tags: ruby, rake, ruby-2.0, rake-test

I have a testing "bootstrap" Ruby script that handles test setup (requires libraries, prepares test variables etc.) and I want the Rake TestTask to run this file before it runs the tests. Is this possible?

I know that Rake starts the test in a new Ruby instance, so doing setup in the Rakefile won't work. [The docs](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/TestTask.html) say that I can pass options to the Ruby command using `TestTask.ruby_opts`, but I haven't been able to find a Ruby option that executes a script file before the main script. I did find:

```
-rlibrary       require the library before executing your script
```

But that doesn't let me reference my testing bootstrap script

Comment: Can't you load the bootstrap script in the test file?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't let me reference my testing bootstrap script"? There's an error? What?

Comment: @toro2k: My test bootstrap script is just a script outside my lib path, I can't load it using `require`

Comment: @ovhaag: if there was just one test file, sure. There could be hundreds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is to include the directory where your script is to the `$LOAD_PATH` passing the `-I` options to the `ruby` command, for example if your script is `some_directory/your_script.rb`, you can execute it like this:

```
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  # ...
  t.ruby_opts = ['-I some_directory', '-r your_script']
end
```